# How do I stop AssertionError messages from subprocess.check_call() in unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a test that is calling a script using subprocess.check_call.  I have assertions inside the script checking the validity of the arguments and I want to check the error cases.  So I've done this:

```
try:
    self.assertRaises(subprocess.CalledProcessError, subprocess.check_call, ['myscript.py', 'myBadArgument'])
except AssertionError:
    pass
```

The test actually passes since the correct assertion gets raised, but I want to keep the assertion messages and associated stack dump from getting printed to the screen.

How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: `except AssertionError` doesn't do anything for errors in the called process, and if it did, you wouldn't get the CalledProcessError you want. All `except AssertionError` does here is silence the error from your own `assertRaises` if you *don't* get the CalledProcessError you want.

Answer (score 3):

To suppress the subprocess's error messages, redirect its stderr:

```
from subprocess import DEVNULL

with self.assertRaises(subprocess.CalledProcessError):
    subprocess.run(['myscript.py', 'myBadArgument'], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

Also, don't catch `AssertionError`. That doesn't do anything to suppress the subprocess's error messages; it only causes your test to incorrectly pass even if the subprocess doesn't raise an error.

Comment: I did not know about DEVNULL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that I was overusing the `assert()` statement.  I was using `assert` to check for things such as whether the user gave me files that existed, or values that made sense in the script.

This was a misunderstanding on my part.  I now see that the correct approach is to check the data and raise the appropriate exceptions in my library elements, then catch those exceptions in my user-facing scripts and provide a call-stack free message.

Once I cleaned this up my test passed with the correct exceptions and with no unneeded messages.

Comment: That sounds like you printed your messages to stdout instead of stderr. `subprocess.check_output` automatically captures stdout, but not stderr, so your messages would have been automatically captured. stderr is usually the appropriate stream to print error messages. EDIT: wait, you're using `check_call`, not `check_output`...